# Вывод данных в отформатированном виде в консоль на Golang, как сделать?

Tags: golang

Есть структуры с данными и такой код:

```
type Vokzal struct {
    Buses []Reis`yaml:"buses"`
}
type Reis struct {
    Name  string `yaml:"name"`
    Number string `yaml:"number"`
}

....
y := Vokzal{}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", y)
```

Вывод в консоли который получается с этим кодом:

```
{Buses:[{Name:Щелково Number:103} {Name:Видное Number:108} {Name:Красногорск Number:118}]}
```

А как сделать такой вывод данных в консоли, то есть переформатировать вывод, чтобы было так:

```
Направление:Щелково Маршрут:103
Направление:Видное Маршрут:108
Направление:Красногорск Маршрут:118
```

Comment: сделать цикл? а внутри аккуратно выводить каждую запись?

Comment: а как? можно пример пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто делаем цикл и аккуратненько выводим. Где то так

```
for _, s := range y.Buses {
        fmt.Printf("Направление: %s Маршрут: %s\n",s.Name, s.Number)
}
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, то что нужно! а как полученный из цикла отформатированный список поставить в  http.HandleFunc("/buses", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Fprint(w, y.Buses) }) на место y.Buses ?

Comment: заменить `fmt.Printf(` на `fmt.Fprintf(w,`. Да, прям так

Comment: Не понял, можно пожалуйста поподробнее) А понял)))

Comment: в моем примере просто сделайте замену. И все.`for _, s := range y.Buses {
        fmt.Fprintf(w,"Направление: %s Маршрут: %s\n",s.Name, s.Number)
}` (в комментариях форматирование портится, так что как то сами)

Comment: Спасибо вам! Всё получилось!